# Repeating the same query snapshot, bringing in same data, despite new data being added to firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have been following the documentation to create a query search in my database to obtain the top scores to display in a tableView.

The code below works, however, when a new (higher score) is added, the tableview is still displaying the old query data.

E.g I have three top scores in my database.. [121, 131, 134]. After the first query these are displayed correctly.

I then continue to play and add some more scores, [121, 131, 134, 234, 432] but the same results are shown in my tableView [121, 131, 134].

I am limiting my display to three items. So it should really show ..... [134, 234, 432].

I have tried clearing my tableView with

```
    scoresArray.removeAll()
    topScoresTableView.reloadData()
```

(This is called when I leave the VC) But this had no effect.

```
class ScoreClass {

let db = Firestore.firestore()


var name = ""
var score = 0

init(withName: String, andScore: Int) {
    name = withName
    score = andScore
}
}

let ref = Database.database().reference()

func retrieveUserData() {

    let postsRef = self.db.collection("users")

    let query = postsRef
                    .whereField("highScore", isGreaterThan: 5000)
                    .order(by: "highScore", descending: false)
                    .limit(to: 3)

    query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    let dict = document.data()
                    let name = dict["username"] as! String
                    let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
                    let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
                    self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
                }
            self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.scoresArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = topScoresTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let scoreClassObject = scoresArray[row]
    let name = scoreClassObject.name
    let score = scoreClassObject.score
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.usernameLabel.text = name
    cell.resultLabel.text = String(score)
    cell.rankNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    print(scoresArray)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't arranging to receive realtime updates from Firestore.  It is just querying Firestore a single time with [getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#/c:objc(cs)FIRQuery(im)getDocumentsWithCompletion:).

What you will have to do instead is change your code to [listen to realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) using [addSnapshotListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#/c:objc(cs)FIRQuery(im)addSnapshotListener:), then update your TableView every time your listener is invoked, when the results of the query change over time.